# "position: absolute" not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to give an absolute position to an image but it's not woking at all!

Here's my test code:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.content{
position: relative;
}

.logo{
position: absolute;
top: 400px;
left: 400px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div class="content">
<div class="logo">
<img src="logo.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Help, please?

Comment: What about it isn't working? What's wrong?

Comment: works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9pH2/)

Comment: It works for me as well. If the other code would override it, use `position:absolute !important;` to fix it.

Comment: Note that you can position the IMG directly with CSS; you don't need the "div.logo" div. Also, if you're using XHTML doctype, your code isn't valid, which sometimes causes strange errors.

Comment: In jsfiddle.net it works! But direct from the browser it doesn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me. Here's a screenshot of what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKyFn.png

You can also see the file I used at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16321997/CSS/absolute_CSS_positioning.html

Is this what you are looking for, or are you trying to do something different?

Comment: It will always stay at 400 pixels from the top and 400 pixels from the left, so if you resize your browser window below that size, you might have to scroll to see the image.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining. They use "float:left;margin:0 3% .25em;" for the logo code (so put that in the curly braces {} for .logo). You can change the numbers based on what looks good to you.